# Restoring StaticFileModule in IIS

Tags: iis, iis-7

How do you restore the default handler mappings? I accidentally deleted the StaticFileModule in the DefaultWebSite and now I can't bring it back.

Additionally, Reverting to Parent doesn't bring it back.

Answer (score 0):

Reverting should do it if the change was just for the default web site.  Check out your web.config file for DefaultWebSite using notepad.  You should see a  for StaticFileModule.  You can manually remove that and save the file.